# SFML - C# Garbage Collector deletes object which is in use

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, sfml

I'm using SFML for C#. I want to create a BackgroundImage Sprite and then start drawing it with an Agent, represented as a Circle, on top of it like that:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode((uint)map.Size.X * 30, (uint)map.Size.Y * 30), map.Name + " - MAZE", Styles.Default);

        while (Window.IsOpen)
        {
            Update();
        }
    }
    static public RenderWindow Window { get; private set; }
    static Map map = new Map(string.Format(@"C:\Users\{0}\Desktop\Maze.png", Environment.UserName));

    static public void Update()
    {
        Window.Clear(Color.Blue);

        DrawBackground();
        DrawAgent();

        Window.Display();
    }

    static void DrawAgent()
    {
        using (CircleShape tempCircle = new CircleShape
        {
            FillColor = Color.Cyan,
            Radius = 15,
            Position = new Vector2f(30, 30),
            Origin = new Vector2f(30, 30),
            Scale = new Vector2f(.5f, .5f)
        })
        {
            Window.Draw(tempCircle);
        }

    }

    static private Sprite BackgroundImage { get; set; }
    static void DrawBackground()
    {
        if (BackgroundImage == null)
            BackgroundImage = GetBackground();

        Window.Draw(BackgroundImage);

    }

    static Sprite GetBackground()
    {
        RenderTexture render = new RenderTexture((uint)map.Size.X * 30, (uint)map.Size.Y * 30);
        foreach (var point in map.Grid.Points)
        {
            RectangleShape pointShape = new RectangleShape(new Vector2f(30, 30));
            switch (point.PointType)
            {
                case PointType.Walkable:
                    pointShape.FillColor = Color.White;
                    break;
                case PointType.NotWalkable:
                    pointShape.FillColor = Color.Black;
                    break;
                case PointType.Start:
                    pointShape.FillColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                case PointType.Exit:
                    pointShape.FillColor = Color.Blue;
                    break;
            }
            pointShape.Position = new Vector2f(point.Position.X * 30, point.Position.Y * 30);
            render.Draw(pointShape);

        }
        Sprite result = new Sprite(render.Texture);
        result.Origin = new Vector2f(0, result.GetLocalBounds().Height);
        result.Scale = new Vector2f(1, -1);
        return result;
    }
```

Everything works as intended when I start it, but after a few seconds, around the time when process memory reaches 70MB, BackgroundImage turns into completely white sprite. If I change the type of BackgroundImage and GetBackground() to RenderTexture, return "render" object and then change DrawBackground() function like this

```
 void RenderBackground()
        {
            if (BackgroundImage == null)
                BackgroundImage = GetBackground();

            using (Sprite result = new Sprite(BackgroundImage.Texture))
            {
                result.Origin = new Vector2f(0, result.GetLocalBounds().Height);
                result.Scale = new Vector2f(1, -1);
                Window.Draw(result);
            }
        }
```

then the background sprite doesn't turn white, but storing entire RenderTexture, instead of Sprite and then constantly creating new Sprite objects every time we call RenderBackground() function seems like a bad idea.
Is there any way for GetBackground() function to return a Sprite which won't turn white once the function's local "render" variable is destroyed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the answer was simpler that I expected. All I had to to was create new Texture object and then make a Sprite out of it. So instead of

```
Sprite result = new Sprite(render.Texture);
```

I wrote

```
Sprite result = new Sprite(new Texture(render.Texture));
```

Now garbage collector doesn't dispose Sprite's texture

Answer (score 1):

You're not completely off with your assumptions. Simplified, SFML knows two types of resources:

- **Light resources** are small objects that are quick to create and destroy. It's not that bad to just drop them and recreate them later. Typical examples would be `Sprite`, `Sound`, `Text`, and basically most SFML classes.
- **Heavy resourcces** are often big objects or objects requiring file access to create or use. Typical examples would be `Image`, `Texture`, `SoundBuffer`, and `Font`. You shouldn't recreate these and instead keep them alive while you need them. If they're disposed too early, light resources using them will fail in some way or another.

A sprite's texture turning white is – as you've discovered – a typical sign of the assigned texture being freed/disposed.

There are many different approaches to this, but I'd suggest you create some kind of simple resource manager that will load resources just in time or just return them, if they're loaded already.

I haven't used SFML with C# and I haven't really touched C# for quite a while, but for a simple implementation you'd just have a `Dictionary<string, Texture>`. When you want to load a texture file like `texture.png`, you look whether there's a dictionary entry with that key name. If there is, just return it. If there isn't, create the new entry and load the texture, then return it.

I'm out of practice, so please consider this pseudo code!

```
private Dictionary<string, Texture> mTextureCache; // initialized in constructor

public Texture getTexture(file) {
    Texture tex;
    if (mTextureCache.TryGetValue(file, out tex))
        return tex;
    tex = new Texture(file);
    mTextureCache.add(file, tex);
    return tex;
}

// Somewhere else in your code:
Sprite character = new Sprite(getTexture("myCharacter.png"));
```

If your heavy resource is a `RenderTexture`, you just have to ensure that it stays alive as long as it's used (e.g. as a separate member).